# how to access params in a before_destroy callback in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I write a before_destroy callback for the following controller:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
   ....

   def destroy
      @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
      current_user.unfollow(@user)
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to @user }
         format.js
      end
   end
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
    validates :follower_id, presence: true
    validates :followed_id, presence: true
    before_destroy :delete_car_permissions 

    private

    def delete_car_permissions
       car_ids = followed.car_ids
       Permission.where("thing_id IN (?) AND user_id = ?", car_ids, follower).delete_all
    end
end
```

The delete_car_permissions doesn't work since I cannot access params in the model!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `params[:id]` to identify the `Relationship`, because `before_destroy` callback runs on instance, not on class.

It is enough to have:

```
    def delete_car_permissions
        car_ids = followed.car_ids
        Permission.where("thing_id IN (?) AND user_id = ?", car_ids, follower).delete_all
    end
```

Comment: I tried but it is not deleting from Permission! Looks like car_ids is being set...

Comment: Could you include `unfollow` method source code to your question?

Comment: Did you check `car_ids`? I assume it's empty.

Comment: No sorry the car_ids is set. so you were right. the problem is with self.id! since it is in the Relationship model the current_user id is not being set. self.id is the id in the Relationship model not the :follower_id! Please look above and let me know if it makes sense..!

Comment: Please update your answer if it makes sense to you to reflect the proper answer this way I can accept your answer. There is a typo as well. It should be :delete_car_permissions!

Comment: please fix the typo where you define the method! ought to be "delete_car_permissions"